# Rails: link_to parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing, link-to, constraintexception

I am completely new to Rails and still have a problem with sending parameters through this link from the ListaUsuarios View, despite trying and researching for many hours now:

```
<%= link_to "Agregar", @solicitud_contacto, method: :post %>
```

It does go to the create action as expected, since I have set

```
resources :solicitud_contactos
```

in the routes.rb. However I get the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in SolicitudContactosController#create

SQLite3::ConstraintException: solicitud_contactos.solicitante_id may not be NULL: INSERT INTO "solicitud_contactos" ("created_at", "solicitado_id", "solicitante_id", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Just to explain, since the question arose: SolicitudContacto is supposed to be a demand for adding another user ("friendship" or "contact" demand), so that the second user can then accept or reject the demand. So I simply want to save such a demand in the database when somebody clicks on the link. "Usuario" (attribute type in the "SolicitudContacto" model) simply means "User".

Also, the way I get it, the following link should get an equivalent result:

```
<%= link_to "Agregar", solicitud_contacto_path(@solicitud_contacto), method: :post %>
```

but it gets me a different error. Apparently here the ids are transferred, but the link goes to the show action instead.

```
Routing Error

No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"solicitud_contactos", :id=>#<SolicitudContacto id: nil, solicitante_id: 2, solicitado_id: 4, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>}
```

I get the same problem with the

```
<%= link_to "Rechazar", @solicitud_contacto, :method => :delete %>
```

in the same view.

*edit: Thanks to Baldricks comment at least the delete link now works, I did not remember that I have to use an actual object from the database. So replacing the corresponding if block by the following does the work:*

```
  <% if (index = @solicitantes.index { |solic| solic.solicitante.id == usuario.id }) != nil %>
    <%= link_to "Rechazar", @solicitantes[index], :method => :delete %>
```

The @solicitud_contacto object with the corresponding ids for

@solicitud_contacto.solicitante.id
  @solicitud_contacto.solicitado.id

are definitely set though as I have them printed out in the same view for testing. I hope someone can help me, because this has really been kind of frustrating... Thanks a lot!

P.S.:

I also read that this:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

should be set in the application.html.erb. It is!

Here ist the relevant code:

SolicitudContacto Model

```
class SolicitudContacto < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :solicitado_id, :solicitante_id
  belongs_to :solicitado, class_name: "Usuario"
  belongs_to :solicitante, class_name: "Usuario"
end
```

SolicitudContacto Controller

```
class SolicitudContactosController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @solicitud = SolicitudContacto.new(params[:solicitud_contacto])
    @solicitud.save
    redirect_to :controller => SearchUsersController, :action => BusquedaUsuarios
  end

  def destroy
    @solicitud = SolicitudContacto.find(params[:id])
    @solicitud.destroy
    redirect_to :controller => SearchUsersController, :action => BusquedaUsuarios
  end

  def index
    @solicitudes = SolicitudContacto.all
  end

  def new
  end

  def show
    @solicitud = SolicitudContacto.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

SearchUsersController

```
class SearchUsersController < ApplicationController

  def BusquedaUsuarios
    @usuario = Usuario.new
  end

  def ListaUsuarios
    # DELETE!!!!!
    $current_usuario = Usuario.find(2)

    @cur_usuario = $current_usuario;
    @solicitud_contacto = SolicitudContacto.new
    @usuario = Usuario.new(params[:usuario])
    @filtros = Hash.new(0);
    if @usuario.nombre != ""
    @filtros["nombre"] = @usuario.nombre
    end
    if @usuario.apellido != ""
    @filtros["apellido"] = @usuario.apellido
    end
    if @usuario.email != ""
    @filtros["email"] = @usuario.email
    end
    @solicitados = @cur_usuario.solicitantes
    @solicitantes = @cur_usuario.solicitados
    @contactos = @cur_usuario.user1s + @cur_usuario.user2s
    @usuarios = Usuario.where(@filtros).order(:nombre).all
  end
end
```

ListaUsuarios (User List View of the SearchUsersController)

```
<h1>SearchUsers#ListaUsuarios</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/search_users/ListaUsuarios.html.erb</p>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Nombre</th>
    <th>Apellido</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>

  <% @usuarios.each do |usuario| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= usuario.nombre %></td>
      <td><%= usuario.apellido %></td>
      <td><%= usuario.email %></td>
      <td>
      <% @solicitud_contacto.solicitante = @cur_usuario %>
      <% @solicitud_contacto.solicitado = usuario %>
    <br>
      <%= @solicitud_contacto.solicitante.id %>
      <%= @solicitud_contacto.solicitado.id %>
    <br>
      <!-- responder la solicitud -->
      <% if @solicitantes.index { |solic| solic.solicitante.id == usuario.id } != nil %>
        <%= link_to "Rechazar", @solicitud_contacto, :method => :delete %>
      <!-- solicitud ya fue mandada -->
      <% elsif @solicitados.index { |solic| solic.solicitado.id == usuario.id } != nil %>
        Esperando Respuesta
      <!-- solicitar contacto -->
      <% else %>
        <%= link_to "Agregar", @solicitud_contacto, method: :post %>
      <% end %>
      </td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a link to the show or delete action, you must do it with a persisted object (i.e. an object an object with an ID created in the DB). In the controller you're doing

```
@solicitud_contacto = SolicitudContacto.new
```

The object is instantiated, but is not created in the DB (you must call `save` or `create` for this). It has no ID.

How to solve your problem ? I'm not sure, I don't understand what you're trying to achieve. I think the link to target is wrong, it should be `@solicitud_contacto.solicitante`

```
<% if @solicitantes.any? { |solic| solic.id == usuario.id }  %>
    <%= link_to "Rechazar", @solicitud_contacto.solicitante, :method => :delete %>
...
```

Comment: @user3070390 The create link looks like this: `<%= link_to "Create", new_solicitud_contacto_path %>`  There's no object or id to provide.

Comment: Thanks, that helped to fix the delete link. However I am still not sure how to deal with the create link. I mean it does not really make sense to me to save the object before calling the create action, especially since in general most likely the action will not be called. It is precisely what I want to happen in the create action... So how can I pass the object to the create action without saving it first? I also tried to put @solicitud_contacto.solicitante instead as the target, but it will take me to the UsuarioController (i.e. UserController) as expected. I will update the description a bit

Comment: Just read your other comment.. However that will take me to the 'new' action. Also I might miss something here, but if I do not pass any argument then how will the action determine which contact demand (SolicitudContacto) it is supposed to create? Still thanks a lot for the support! Especially with the delete link.

Comment: Now that I actually got the difference between the two issues I had I suppose it is just not possible to realize the create call the way I was trying to. I have to use a form to POST parameters, so it seems I must go back to the hidden fields I originally had and then figure out how to restyle the "Submit" button.

Comment: Right, if you want to create link directly to the `create`, it's better to use an hidden form instead of a link.